# How to build a CT scan into a printable 3D model?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

I have a set of 2D pictures from a CT scan.

How can I convert them into a 3D model for 3D printing? An example looks like this:

[image: CT-Scan of a mouse's bones]

Comment: What is your question? how to convert 2D slices int 3D model?

Comment: You can use MITK

Answer (score 4):

Using the terms "convert CT scan to 3D model," I found a number of links of tutorials. One of them is described as free, with registration and appears to be web based. The link, [Embodi3D](https://www.embodi3d.com/blogs/entry/345-a-ridiculously-easy-way-to-convert-ct-scans-to-3d-printable-bone-stl-models-for-free-in-minutes/), appears to have a relatively comprehensive set of instructions to accomplish your goal.

[Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-convert-medical-scan-data-into-a-3D-printab/) also has a similar tutorial. Should neither of these prove suitable, the search terms above may be of value.

Image below via Instructables:
[image: bone scan]

Comment: Fred, this is a *bit* of a link only answer. If the links die, then the answer won't be terribly useful, apart from the search terms... :-) Any chance of including the main steps?

Comment: I attempt tp avoid link only answers, as I've seen reference regarding dead links. In both linked suggestions, the quantity of steps are substantial and detailed. My primary purpose was to suggest useful search terms.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the layer thickness, you can **manually** re-engineer/design the object:

- take your CAD or 3D modeling program of choice

  1. import one picture into the XY axis
  2. trace the outline on that layer
  3. add a construction layer one layer thickness above
- Rinse 1-3 and repeat for all layers.
- Combine the outlines, method depending on your program

  - this might be quite easy in blender if you add the new *layer* by extruding the previous one up by one layer thickness and just move the vertices to match the new outline
- finally, export the model as `.stl` depending on your program, slice and print.